# Compare current time with specific time when some event occures

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

In the code below, only the `else` part is ever getting executed. What should I do to execute the `if` part?

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Current Time is 11:47:00 AM
    DateTime CurrentTime = System.DateTime.Now;
    DateTime StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime("10:15:00 AM");
    DateTime Stoptime = Convert.ToDateTime("02:29:57 PM");
    DateTime CloseTime = Convert.ToDateTime("02:59:57 PM");

    if (StartTime > CurrentTime && CurrentTime < Stoptime)
    {
        // CODE
    }
    else
    {
        // CODE
    }
}
```

Comment: `If` part will be executed when the conditions are met? In your case, the `if` part won't be executed because your StartTime is earlier then your CurrentTime. Change to `if (StartTime < CurrentTime && CurrentTime < Stoptime)`

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Can you please be _more_ specific? It would be better to read [ask] as a start in my opinion. If you just wanna compare DateTime values, `<` and `>` operators just works simply.

Comment: if (StartTime < CurrentTime && CurrentTime < Stoptime). update your if statement like this if you want your IF to be excecuted at 11:47:00, first half of IF statement will be false as 10:15 is lesser than 11:47

Comment: i want to execute my 'if' condition in time between 10:15:00  am to 02:30:00 PM

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're checking if `StartTime` is ***greater than*** `CurrentTime`, which it clearly isn't. You just need to swap out that first operator with a ***less than*** operator:

```
if (StartTime < CurrentTime && CurrentTime < Stoptime)
{
    //CODE
}
else
{
    //CODE
}
```

Comment: i want to execute my 'if' condition in time between 10:15:00 am to 02:30:00 PM

so i am checking that is current time is greater than 10:15:00 am and less than 02:30:00 pm

Comment: I know that's what you *want* to do, but you're not. Look at your code. You are checking if `StartTime > CurrentTime`. You want `StartTime < CurrentTime`. When I learned the `>` and `<` operators as a kid, my teacher taught us to look at them as mouths, trying to eat the bigger of the two operands. The wide end always opens towards the larger value. Maybe that helps here?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Boolean IsTimeBetween(DateTime refer, DateTime begin, DateTime end, Boolean inclusive = true)
{
    DateTime from = new DateTime(refer.Year, refer.Month, refer.Day, begin.Hour, begin.Minute, begin.Second, begin.Millisecond);
    DateTime to = new DateTime(refer.Year, refer.Month, refer.Day, end.Hour, end.Minute, end.Second, end.Millisecond);

    if (inclusive)
        return ((from <= refer) && (to >= refer));

    return ((from < refer) && (to > refer));
}
```

This will never get you wrong:

```
Boolean between = IsTimeBetween(CurrentTime, StartTime, StopTime);
```

Comment: Any reason not to just compare the `.TimeOfDay` values instead of creating new objects? For example: `return ((begin.TimeOfDay < refer.TimeOfDay) && (end.TimeOfDay > refer.TimeOfDay));`